# Using JIRA Java API to post an attachment to existing issue

Tags: api, jira, attachment

I am trying to post an attachment to an existing issue in JIRA using API, but it is giving me weird errors:

public class JiraRest {

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException 
{
String pathname= "C:/Users/skalbur/Videos/eclipse-jee-mars-R-win32-x86_64/Mars workspace/Desert.jpg"; 
File fileUpload = new File(pathname);

HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost("https://rallytojira.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/issue/FP-1389/attachments");
postRequest.setHeader("X-Atlassian-Token","nocheck");

MultipartEntityBuilder entity = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();    
entity.addPart("file", new FileBody(fileUpload));
postRequest.setEntity((HttpEntity) entity);
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(postRequest);
}
}
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/config/Lookup
at JiraRest.main(JiraRest.java:33)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.http.config.Lookup
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
... 1 more
```

I have used following JARs for my program:

apache-httpcomponents-httpcore.jar, json-simple-1.1.1.jar, httpmime-4.3.jar, jcommander.jar, httpclient-4.3-beta1.jar

Answer (score 0):

THIS CODE WORKS:

```
public class JiraRest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException
    {
        String pathname= "<Full path name of the attachment file>";
        File fileUpload = new File(pathname);
        HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
        HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost("URL+Post REST API");
        BASE64Encoder base=new BASE64Encoder();
        String encoding = base.encode ("username:password".getBytes());
        postRequest.setHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + encoding);
        postRequest.setHeader("X-Atlassian-Token","nocheck");
        MultipartEntityBuilder entity=MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
        entity.addPart("file", new FileBody(fileUpload));
        postRequest.setEntity( entity.build());
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(postRequest);
    }
}
```

Required JARs:
All JARs in lib folder of httpcomponents-client-4.5-bin and sun.misc.BASE64Decoder.jar